# $L^2$ vs. squared $L^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Can please anyone explain this statement from [deep learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/):
The squared norm $L^2$ is more convenient to work with mathematically and
computationally than the $L^2$ norm itself. For example, each derivative of the squared $L^2$ norm with respect to each element of x depends only on the corresponding element of x, while all the derivatives of the $L^2$ norm depend on the entire vector.

From commenter: I compare $‖.‖_2$ with $‖.‖_2^2$.

I know a lot of linear algebra but I just can clarify this statement, so tips are more than welcome.

Comment: do you compare $\|.\|_2$ with $\|.\|_2^2$? If so then I recommend to clarify that, because $L^2$ is not a norm but a vectorspace.

Comment: Yes I do, I used notation from book.

Comment: The main advantage of $\|.\|_2^2$ is that there is no square root: $\|x\|_2^2 = (x,x)$ where $(.,.)$ is the scalar product in $L^2$.

Comment: So, for example, when maximizing $\|\cdot\|_2$ of something, try maximizing instead $\|\cdot\|_2^2$.  Then the derivative is easier to work with.